# Take jsons objects from a file and insert into MongoDB using mongoose in nodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a file "rooms.json" :

```
{ "name": "Computer science class 1" , "location": "Mid School upper floor"}
{ "name": "Computer science class 2" , "location": "Mid School upper floor"}
{ "name": "Computer science class 3" , "location": "Mid School upper floor"}
{ "name": "classG12N1" , "location": "High School building upper floor"}
{ "name": "classG12N2" , "location": "High School building upper floor"}
{ "name": "classG12N3" , "location": "High School building upper floor"}
{ "name": "classG12N4" , "location": "High School building upper floor"}
{ "name": "classG11N1" , "location": "High School building lower floor"}
{ "name": "classG11N2" , "location": "High School building lower floor"}
{ "name": "classG11N3" , "location": "High School building lower floor"}
```

I am using mongoose in nodeJS. I need a function that will read the file, format it in json and insert into the DB.

I have tried reading the file line by line and parsing it myself but it was not efficient at all. Is there any other way?

PS, I have searched the web for some solution but yet to find one.

Comment: Can you change your json file to be an array of objects? That may make it easier to parse

Comment: To add to @wlh 's comment, your `room.json` is not actually valid json the way its written.  Put everything inside array brackets `[...]` to make it parsable

Comment: @bitstrider can you show me that you mean?